# ASIHTTPRequest and NSOperations - Is there any other way to implement Multithreading?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, xcode, cocoa-touch

Apart from  `ASIHTTPRequest` and using `NSOperations` what other ways are there to implement Multithreading? Please provide a link if there are any other ways to implement multithreading.
Also can we implement multithreading for AudioStreaming to retrieve from url..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this method:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(entryPointMethodForSecondThread) toTarget:objectWhereEntryPMethodDeclarated withObject:nil];
```

Note that you must create an autorelease pool for it in 'entry point method'. 
The details check in the specification of NSThread.

Comment: So we can create thread using NSThread and you mean that we can also call another in other seperate thread???

Comment: NSThread here is a class. It has a static method detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject: .  It will create a new thread (whereas your active one will go on), starting it with function you will pass to 'toTarget' parameter. Don't forget to create an autorelease pool in that function.

Comment: ok but I want to know that the method entrypointMethodForSecondThread  will be executed in seperate Thread???

Comment: Yes :) Your main (or active) thread will pass the line I provided in answer, proceeding its work; The second thread will be created at that line and will start its work from entrypointMethodForSecondThread.